# JPA mapping for inserting a relationship

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I am using JPA to persist my entities. Suppose I have a `ManyToMany` relationship between the entity A and B. So, in the class `A` it will be a `List<B>` and in `B` a `List<A>`.

My question is about the efficiency of adding a new relationship. 
In the easy way I can make a `add(new B())` in the list in class `A`. Will this `List` of `B` objects in the class `A` will all be loaded from the database when I call the add method in runtime? Is this efficient?

If I have 200 relationships, it will load all of them, to simply add a new object `B`? It will be better to create a native query to insert a new row the `ManyToMany` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of add() on a List is dependent on the JPA provider.

For EclipseLink, for a LAZY List relationship add() will not cause the list to be fetched by default.

Comment: And in efficiency, what is best? Use the add() or create a native query to insert?

Comment: You want to almost always avoid using native queries when you're using a JPA provider. Unless you really know what you're doing. Good JPA providers exploit DBMS features like caching, pooling and indexing very well.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, JPA providers provide their own implementations of Java Collections which support lazy loading, so not all relationships will be loaded right from the start.

Also, when you modify any of the lists as you described, the JPA provider should transparently update the database. You don't have to worry to keep things consistent, other than references you might have cached on your own.

Answer (score 0):

When it starts to run into the hundreds you might be better off to just map the join table as a JPA entity and not use a ManyToMany mapping but simply perform operations (mutations and selections) directly on the join table with two ManyToOne mappings in there.